# Rails: Pass value from array to strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a textbox 'ohrmarke' where I can enter multiple strings in new lines and once I click on the create button, the values from the textbox will be stripped with '\r\n' and each value gets stored in an array. It all happens in the controllers create method.

Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for Cow.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :ohrmarke, label: "Ohrmarke(n)" %>
    <!-- ... -->
<% end %>
```

Controller create:

```
  def create
    @ohrmarken = params[:cow][:ohrmarke].split("\r\n")
     @ohrmarken.each do |item|
       @cow = Cow.new(cow_params)
       @cow.save
     end
     # (...)
   end
```

For each string I entered in the textbox, I want to create a new cow. However, 'ohrmarke' is not the only input. If that would be the case, I would have entered `@cow = Cow.new(ohrmarke: item)` in the loop and it would have worked. There are other values for a cow that must be saved alongside the single item. That's why I use the cow_params.

```
def cow_params
  params.require(:cow).permit(:ohrmarke, :hin, :weg, :stallnummer, :location_id)
end
```

As you can see, the other fields are 'hin', 'weg', 'stallnummer' and 'location_id'. But 'ohrmarke' must be the value of the item. However I can't write ohrmarke: item because I get the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
```

This also happens if I insert a test value like `ohrmarke: 'test'`. The error still stays if I use `:ohrmarke => 'test'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Remove `ohrmarke` from `cow_params`

```
def cow_params
  params.require(:cow).permit(:hin, :weg, :stallnummer, :location_id)
end
```

And inside your loop try to set `ohrmarke` like this

```
@cow = Cow.new(cow_params)
@cow.ohrmarke = item
@cow.save
```